# Why does my Selenium script fail on password element?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this selenium script that can enter email address, hit the use password button but then fails on entering the password:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

web = webdriver.Chrome()
web.implicitly_wait(5)
web.get('https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=16&ct=1700481689&rver=7.0.6738.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fowa%2f%3fcobrandid%3dab0455a0-8d03-46b9-b18b-df2f57b9e44c%26nlp%3d1%26deeplink%3dowa%252f%26RpsCsrfState%3de98b3d70-89d0-6e78-6a87-b7d5b1245a4e&id=292841&aadredir=1&CBCXT=out&lw=1&fl=dob%2cflname%2cwld&cobrandid=ab0455a0-8d03-46b9-b18b-df2f57b9e44c')

EmailSignIn = web.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='i0116']")
EmailSignIn.send_keys("generic@live.com")

web.implicitly_wait(5)

EMailSignInContinueButton = web.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='idSIButton9']")
EMailSignInContinueButton.click()

web.implicitly_wait(5)

UsePasswordButton = web.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='idA_PWD_SwitchToPassword']")
UsePasswordButton.click()

web.implicitly_wait(5)

SelectEMailPasswordBox = web.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='i0118']")
SelectEMailPasswordBox.send_keys("FakePassword")

time.sleep(5)
```

Had no issues with the rest of the script so I am thinking there must be something funky about password boxes I don't know? Other online information seems outdated. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Tried to run script as above, fails on entering the password. Would like password to be populated in outlook.

Comment: Are you sure that the passwordbox element is being found? add some debug statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause of the issue:** No need of the below line. I don't see anything in the HTML with attribute `ID=idA_PWD_SwitchToPassword`. (***Unless I am missing something, or there is additional screen/button displaying to you but not to me on my system***)

```
UsePasswordButton = web.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='idA_PWD_SwitchToPassword']")
UsePasswordButton.click()
```

**Check the below working refactored code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

web = webdriver.Chrome()
web.maximize_window()
web.get('https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=16&ct=1700481689&rver=7.0.6738.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fowa%2f%3fcobrandid%3dab0455a0-8d03-46b9-b18b-df2f57b9e44c%26nlp%3d1%26deeplink%3dowa%252f%26RpsCsrfState%3de98b3d70-89d0-6e78-6a87-b7d5b1245a4e&id=292841&aadredir=1&CBCXT=out&lw=1&fl=dob%2cflname%2cwld&cobrandid=ab0455a0-8d03-46b9-b18b-df2f57b9e44c')
wait = WebDriverWait(web,15)

EmailSignIn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='i0116']")))
EmailSignIn.send_keys("generic@live.com")

EMailSignInContinueButton = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='idSIButton9']")))
EMailSignInContinueButton.click()

SelectEMailPasswordBox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='i0118']")))
SelectEMailPasswordBox.send_keys("FakePassword")

time.sleep(20)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: That is weird. I was getting, before, a screen where it wanted me to use authenticator but there was a hyperlink to click "use password instead". I think it was for that...anyway it doesn't seem to be coming up anymore so I have removed that part of the code and it is running fine now. Thank you so much!